# Trouble animating Menu component

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions, vue-component

I am having trouble animating the menu component, which is expected to slide in and out on click, while the background fades in and out. I have in and out classes, depending on a 'showMenu' Boolean. In the sandbox, the menu flies in and out instantly when I click the Vue logo, but in my local version, everything works when they slide/fade in, but nothing happens when the menu closes. I am using the Bootstrap modal for this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nk2xnz2wp0

Comment: Try doing it with [vue transitions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

Comment: I have tried to do it with vue transitions, specifically:
1. I tried to wrap the component inside App, but I can't fade the background. 
2. I tried using vue transition inside the Menu, but still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I don't see any trace of Vue's `<transition />`. Do you?

Answer (score 1):

As another user said, [vue transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) are designed for this. You're code appeared to be overly complicated, I would advise against passing a function as a property. Vue has very good documentation about communication between child and parent components, I think maybe this is where your issues were arising from. I have modified your code to include a very basic vue transition and the menu now fades in and out, see https://codesandbox.io/s/0m13wz25pl?fontsize=14.

For possible future readers, the main code involved is:

```
<template>
  <transition name="fade">
    <HelloWorld v-on:click="showMenu = !showMenu;" v-if="showMenu" />
  </transition>
</tempalte>

<style>
  .fade-enter-active,
  .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 2s;
  }
  .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
     opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Like I mentioned above, I already tried that, but I can't fade in the background, that's why I tried toggling classes inside the menu component.

Answer (score 0):

Inside App I made a separate div for the background and did a separate Vue transition for menu and the background div like so:

```
  <transition name="slide-menu" mode="in-out">
    <MenuDrawer v-if="showMenu" :toggleMenu="toggleMenu" />
  </transition>

  <transition name="fade" mode="in-out">
    <div class="darkBg" v-if="showMenu"></div>
  </transition>
```

It definitely feels dirty, and I hope someone can show me a better solution.

Comment: Why dirty? If you are applying different transition behaviours then placing the menu and background elements within different transition tags makes perfect sense. The above code is very readable and makes good use of in-built functionality.

Comment: Well, the bg belongs to the Menu, not the App. It's bad for reusability. This might well be a modal used in several components.